# How can I get active directory users and computers to display unicode characters in user names?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, unicode

In a test environment, we are seeing how you can manage Japanese usernames and english usernames on a Windows 2012 R2 domain controller in Windows 2012 domain.

AdsiEdit.msc displays Japanese usernames correctly but Active Directory Users and Computers does not, it shows underscores where the characters should be. Furthermore, any attempt to bring up the properties of the users in AD users/computers produces an "object cannot be displayed" error.

How can I get active directory users and computers to display unicode characters in user names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Language Pack (MUI):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win81

Comment: Ha, well that was painfully obvious! I thought you only did that if you want to alter the interface language, silly me! Interesting how some tools (adsi edit) just work anyway!

Comment: Make sure you test this. Some hotfixes may need to be reinstalled if a language pack is installed after a hotfix.  If required, it will be noted in the KB article.